# Google contacts stopped syncing

Tags: contacts, sync

I've had my HTC Evo since it came out a year ago.  My Google contacts synced flawlessly numerous times during this period.

I rooted my phone on 5/23 with unrevoked, and everything still seemed to be fine.  I only add this for the small chance that rooting is involved.  I have not applied the gingerbread update, and I haven't done a system update since the last OTA forever ago.

According to the accounts and sync screen, the last time my contacts synced was on 6/7.  Since this was a week ago, I can't really think of anything I could've done that would break my contact syncing.  When I go and try to resync, it acts like it's trying, and it doesn't change the sync date.  Also, data isn't going between my phone and my Gmail account.

Gmail and calendar syncing seem to work fine.  I haven't noticed any other issues.  Any clue as to what could cause this and how to fix it?

Comment: Try setting the contacts to "not-sync", then enable again, and reboot the device if you haven't.

Comment: I have a similar issue on my phone, contacts does not sync anymore, see. http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116921/how-can-i-force-a-complete-new-sync-of-my-google-contacts-to-my-phone/117064#117064 - interesting: this happened around the same time, the last sync time was May 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as the night progressed, and I tried various fixes such as what Nathan suggested and restoring from Titanium backups and such, my problems simply got worse.

I ended up simply backing up my application data and restoring from a nandroid backup.  That seems to have fixed it.  It may have been a virus, or I might've corrupted something somehow.  After I restored the backup, the contacts are syncing just fine.

Comment: Restoring from a backup sounds like a good idea (I have a similar issue here) - did you restore only the contacts data or the complete phone? I would like to avoid going back with the backup a couple of month ago to a time where my contacts were still syncing ... and loose all other data I changed in that time ...

Comment: I restored the entire phone.  I backed up the individual apps beforehand, though.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `Settings > Accounts and Sync`
2. Open up your GMail account there
3. Deselect the Contacts option
4. Select it again and quit

This will force Android to sync it **:)**

Comment: I tried that.  The error was deeper than that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was caused by having a YouTube account registered on my phone as a Google account. Until this point, I only had a single Google account and it all worked fine, but after adding the YouTube account it seemed to stop a lot of things from working correctly on my normal Google account.

This was resolved by removing the YouTube account from my Accounts And Sync settings.

Answer (score 0):

Also check you have enough free space in your mobile phone. I had similar Problem, and cleared out lot of junk files - social media downloads in whatsapp messaging, facebook and other apps.
Then Google accounts - contacts, keepnotes and other apps started syncing smoothly.

Comment: This question is over 10 years old, and already has an accepted answer.  Your answer would be better served on a more recent version of this question.