# How can I force a complete new sync of my Google contacts to my phone?

Tags: contacts, sync, google, cache

I would like to force a fresh download of all my google contacts to my phone (and before delete all the google contacts I do have on my phone ... as the sync on my phone got confused and keeps [creating thousands of duplicates](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/116789/contacts-sync-problem-gmail-685-on-android-phone-5460-with-hundreds-of-duplic) which is kind of annoying and slows my phone down quite a bit ...

Is this possible? I guess, I should not delete the contacts on my phone, as might cause to delete the contacts in my google account as well.

Does anyone know where the contacts are cached on the phone? And is it possible to delete the cache in order to force a re-sync?

There are a couple of apps that seem to relate to contacts:

- com.android.providers.contacts "Kontakte-Speicher" (Contacts Storage)
- com.android.contacts "Kontakte" (Contacts)
- com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts "Google Kontakte
  synchronisieren" (Google Contacts Sync)

Which of those does store the google contacts?
Are the contacts stored in the data memory or in the cache?

Comment: I just realized that my google contact sync got somehow messed up and does not sync anymore. The sync starts and then it stops and shows May 22 as last sync date ... I deleted all the caches of the 3 apps mentioned above - but sync still does not work. Any idea what else I could try?

Comment: Update: I removed my Google account from my phone, then deleted all data of the Apps: Contacts, Contacts Storage and Google Contact Sync, rebooted the phone and added my Google account again. Result: All my Google contacts are gone (and the phone is suddenly quite fast again! :-) - however, it does not work to sync my Google contacts back (my LinkedIn contacts are still there). When I go to `Settings > Accounts (Google) > my Gmail account` it shows that all different apps have synched, however the "sync" icon stays visible for the contatcs, while it disappears for all other Apps after sync.

Comment: I really had expected that removing the account will solve the sync issue .... any hints? But actually, this question is answered now, the remaining question is, how to fix my broken sync of contacts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did:

I removed my Google account from my phone, then deleted all data of the Apps: Contacts, Contacts Storage and Google Contact Sync, rebooted the phone and added my Google account again. Result: All my Google contacts are gone (and the phone is suddenly quite fast again! :-)

... however, it does not work to sync my Google contacts back (my LinkedIn contacts are still there). When I go to `Settings > Accounts (Google) > my Gmail account` it shows that all different apps have synched, however the "sync" icon stays visible for the contatcs, while it disappears for all other Apps after sync. –  Pedi T. 1 min ago   edit

I really had expected that removing the account will solve the sync issue .... any hints? But actually, this question is answered now, the remaining question is, how to fix my broken sync of contacts ...

Comment: Finally I did a (backup +) factory reset, now it works again.

Comment: Just removing the Google account and readding it solved the problem for me.